# Plot xarray requires 2d array

Tags: python-xarray

I have an xarray Data array:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (index: 16200)
Coordinates:
  * index      (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 16194 16195 16196 16197 16198 16199
    LONG       (index) float64 -179.0 -179.0 -179.0 -179.0 ... 179.0 179.0 179.0
    LAT        (index) float64 -89.0 -87.0 -85.0 -83.0 ... 83.0 85.0 87.0 89.0
Data variables:
    ELEVATION  (index) float64 2.965e+03 2.915e+03 ... -3.822e+03 -3.392e+03
    MOHO       (index) float64 -3.888e+04 -3.888e+04 ... -1.457e+04 -1.457e+04
    LAB        (index) float64 -1.2e+05 -1.2e+05 ... -1.245e+05 -1.245e+05
    RHO_C      (index) float64 2.851e+03 2.851e+03 ... 2.806e+03 2.806e+03
    RHO_L      (index) float64 3.33e+03 3.33e+03 ... 3.35e+03 3.346e+03
    RHO_SL     (index) float64 3.437e+03 3.437e+03 ... 3.443e+03 3.443e+03
    BOTTOM     (index) float64 -4.1e+05 -4.1e+05 -4.1e+05 ... -4.1e+05 -4.1e+05
    GEOID      (index) float64 -0.81 5.01 4.78 0.15 ... 3.28 3.42 1.52 -0.73
    FA         (index) float64 0.82 38.25 36.06 -17.35 ... 6.77 13.84 3.85 -2.68
    G_zz       (index) float64 0.01 0.33 0.22 -0.08 ... 0.07 0.12 0.04 -0.0
    G_xx       (index) float64 0.04 -0.1 -0.1 -0.02 ... -0.12 -0.1 -0.06 -0.04
    G_yy       (index) float64 -0.12 -0.23 -0.12 0.1 ... 0.05 -0.02 0.02 0.04
```

No I would like to plot it:

```
ds.LAB.plot.contourf()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: DataArray must be 2d
```

Which I don't understand. It knows the latitude and longitude of the thing, the only thing it needs to do is plot the z-value corresponding to the lat/lon for any index. I don't see the need for a 2D array here.

Who could explain this?

Many thanks!

Comment: LAT and LONG are listed as coordinates, but not as dimensions. Your data set only contain one dimension named `index`. This means that every variable is 1-dimensional and cannot be plotted using a function that requires 2-dimensional input data.

Comment: You could try something crazy like `ds.["LAB"].reshape(180,90).plot.contourf()` but than the coordinates maybe don't match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following dataset `ds`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (index: 1325)
Coordinates:
    lon      (index) float32 200.0 200.0 200.0 200.0 ... 330.0 330.0 330.0 330.0
    lat      (index) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 ... 22.5 20.0 17.5 15.0
  * index    (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1318 1319 1320 1321 1322 1323 1324
Data variables:
    air      (index) float32 260.4 262.7 264.8 267.7 ... 295.7 295.8 296.4 297.3
```

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([ds.lat.values, ds.lon.values], names=["lat", "lon"])
ds_new = ds.assign_coords(index=multiindex).unstack()
```

to obtain `ds_new`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 25, lon: 53)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 15.0 17.5 20.0 22.5 25.0 ... 65.0 67.5 70.0 72.5 75.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 ... 322.5 325.0 327.5 330.0
Data variables:
    air      (lat, lon) float32 298.4 298.4 298.1 298.1 ... 250.8 251.9 253.4
```

which allows for:

```
ds_new.air.plot.contourf()
```